# javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError: draw is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code of Graham scan algorithm which finding the convex hull of a finite set of points in the plane, And there are some errors in java script, was looking in internet but didn't find the right answer for all errors.

UPD: So I comented the 64 line of code and all erors disapeared but  the onclick function that shold draw lines doesnt work yet

Here is a html file

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Graham Scan</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>  
            <form>
              <label>Задайте точки (через запятую):</label>
              <input id="points" value="10, 20, 60, 160, 110, 20, -60, 80, 70, 140" size="150" type="text" /> 
              <input type="button" onclick="getPoints()" value="Построить оболочку" /><br />
            </form>
        </body>    
    </html>
```

main.js

```
/**
 * создает канвас
 */
function create_canvas() {
    var canvas_html = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas_html.id = "canvas";
    canvas_html.width = 1500;
    canvas_html.height = 800;

    document.body.appendChild(canvas_html);

    return canvas_html.getContext('2d');
}

/**
 * рисует координатные оси  
 */
function drawCoordLines() {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.moveTo(300, 10);
    canvas.lineTo(300, 400);
    canvas.moveTo(10, 220);
    canvas.lineTo(600, 220);
    canvas.stroke();
    canvas.closePath();
}

/**
 * рисует оболочку
 */
function drawHull() {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.moveTo(300 + points[ h[0] ].x, 220 - points[ h[0] ].y);
    for(var i=1; i<h.length; i++){
        canvas.lineTo(300 + points[ h[i] ].x, 220 - points[ h[i] ].y);
    }

    canvas.closePath();    
    canvas.stroke();    
}

/**
 * рисует точки
 */
function drawPoints() {

    canvas.fillStyle = '#00f';
    for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++){
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.arc(300 + points[i].x, 220 - points[i].y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2); // рисует точку
        canvas.closePath();
        canvas.fill(); 
    }    


}

/**
 * обновляет и перерисовывает канвас
 */
function update() {
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 1500, 800); // очищаем канвас
    drawCoordLines();    
  //  draw();
    drawPoints();
}

/**
 * считывает точки из формы
 */
function getPoints() {
    // получаем строку введенную в форму, и записываем в массив, разбив ее по запятой
    var coords = pointsV.value.split(", ");
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    points = [];
    ch = [];
    while (i < coords.length) {
        points[j++] = {
            'x': parseInt(coords[i++]),
            'y': parseInt(coords[i++])
        }
        ch.push(j-1);
    }    
    graham();
}

/**
 * возращает векторное произведение
 */
function classify(vector, x1, y1) {
    return pr = (vector.x2 - vector.x1) * (y1 - vector.y1) - (vector.y2 - vector.y1) * (x1 - vector.x1);
}

/**
 * Выполняет поиск Грэхема и заполняет массив h, в котором будут перечислены точки, входящие в оболочку
 */
function graham() {
    var minI = 0; //номер нижней левой точки
    var min = points[0].x;
    // ищем нижнюю левую точку
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i].x < min) {
            min = points[i].x;
            minI = i;
        }
    }
    // делаем нижнюю левую точку активной
    ch[0] = minI;
    ch[minI] = 0;

    // сортируем вершины в порядке "левизны"
    for (var i = 1; i < ch.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < ch.length; j++) {
            var cl = classify({
                'x1': points[ ch[0] ].x,
                'y1': points[ ch[0] ].y,
                'x2': points[ ch[i] ].x,
                'y2': points[ ch[i] ].y
            }, points[ ch[j] ].x, points[ ch[j] ].y) // функция classify считает векторное произведение.            

            // если векторное произведение меньше 0, следовательно вершина j левее вершины i.Меняем их местами
            if (cl < 0) {
                temp = ch[i];
                ch[i] = ch[j];
                ch[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   

    //записываем в стек вершины, которые точно входят в оболочку
    h = [];
    h[0] = ch[0];
    h[1] = ch[1]; 


    for (var i = 2; i < ch.length; i++) {
        while (classify({
            'x1': points[ h[h.length - 2] ].x,
            'y1': points[ h[h.length - 2] ].y,
            'x2': points[ h[h.length - 1] ].x,
            'y2': points[ h[h.length - 1] ].y
        }, points[ ch[i] ].x, points[ ch[i] ].y) < 0) {            
            h.pop(); // пока встречается правый поворот, убираем точку из оболочки
        }
        h.push(ch[i]); // добавляем новую точку в оболочку
    }

    // обновляем канвас
    update();
}

/**
 * выполняется когда страница будет полностью загружена в браузер
 */
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = create_canvas();

    // массив точек, из которых строим выпуклую оболочку
    points = [{
            'x': 10,
            'y': 20
        }, {
            'x': 60,
            'y': 160
        }, {
            'x': 110,
            'y': 20
        }, {
            'x': -60,
            'y': 80
        },
        {
            'x': 70,
            'y': 140
        }];

    // массив номеров точек, потребуется для алгоритма Грэхема   
    ch = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

    // искомая оболочка, будет заполнена функцией graham
    h = []

    // получаем форму ввода
    pointsV = document.getElementById('points');
    graham();
}
```

Comment: `draw is not defined` because `draw` is not defined (there is no such function `draw` in your code).

Comment: You have no `function draw()` anywhere in the code. You have `drawCoordLines`, `drawHull`, and `drawPoints`.

Comment: ok. i just deleted that line if code aaand... point appeared on the canvas, but onclick the function that should draw the lines doesnt work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `draw()` function doesn't exist in main.js. You have `drawCoordLines()` and `drawHull()` but not just `draw()`. The error message is very explicit and even gives you the line to look at...

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment, and two of us have already posted it.

Comment: @Barmar there were no comments when I started typing my answer, and I don't have enough rep to post comments because of people like you who down-rep people who are just trying to help.

Comment: Posting inappropriate answers is not the way to gain the rep you'll need to be able to comment. If the comments aren't there, just wait. Did you really think you were the only one who could see what the problem is?

Comment: How is it an inappropriate answer? He wants to know what the error means and I told him. I'm not fishing for rep, I'm trying to help people by answering some simple questions while I wait for my own question to be answered.

Comment: A proper answer should explain how to solve the problem, not just explain the error.

Comment: @Barmar Why do you discourage newcomers from answering questions? I think it's obvious from my account that I'm new here and down-repping me for trying to help is not how you're going to encourage me to become part of the community. You could have told me what was wrong with my answer without down-repping me. You're basically encouraging me to become a leech who only asks questions and never gives answers...

Comment: @Barmar guys) i have a little update in my question. i figure out that draw() is using just 1 time in the code and it doesnt mean anything i think. because i already have a function that draw points. but now the question is why onclick function doesnt work/ Yes i know that i m bad in js

Comment: @AndrewDushkin I think maybe instead of removing draw() you should replace it with drawHull()

Comment: I think it's more an issue of a question that's not very useful for future visitors. And also, as it's a very short answer, it shows up on Low Quality Posts review (where I found your answer). Thanks for trying to help folks, milec!